# Mount - Unable to find suitable address

Tags: mount, samba

I am trying to mount my Windows share through my Ubuntu box (no xwindow), but I continue to get

> Unable to find suitable address

I have tried using the raw IP address, I have checked the credentials, I have disabled the Windows firewall, but I cannot find anything wrong.

```
benny@backup:~$ sudo mount -t cifs //my-desk/j -o username=me,password=s)mePasss /mnt/sync
Unable to find suitable address.
benny@backup:~$ ping my-desk
PING my-desk (10.10.10.43) 56(84) bytes of data.
♥
--- my-desk ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1008ms

benny@backup:~$ sudo mount -t cifs //10.10.10.43/j -o username=me,password=s)mePasss /mnt/sync
Unable to find suitable address.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see the ping fails. Have you connection problems?

Comment: I don't understand why I would. I am connecting through SSH over the same network I'm trying to mount to.  When I try ping now, I get "destination host unreachable", but it resolves the IP ok.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Comment: This is one of the top Google hits for that mount.cifs error message, so I'd like to point out that any connectivity issue that causes a TCP reset or ICMP unreachable message to be sent back to the source could result in it.  In my case it was a firewall between the two hosts.

Comment: In my case, it was simply that the SMB / Samba server on the target server had died.

Answer (score 9):

You might have to explicitly specify the IP address, e.g.:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //my-disk/j -o "username=me,password=s)mePasss,ip=10.10.10.43" /mnt/sync
```

Comment: The OP "tried using the raw IP address." While that was presumably in the part that identifies the share (i.e., `//raw-ip-address/j`), it still seems unlikely that this would work if that does not.

Comment: It does make a difference - if you specify the raw IP address in the UNC, then the client can't send a valid NetBIOS name to the server. Some servers will break if they don't get a valid NetBIOS name.

Comment: For sure, I had solved this issue with the additional `ip=` parameter

Comment: I tried this, doesn't seem to work :(